# How implementation of class helped a object driven programming?

Tags: oop

I am having a very strange question, although I am learning OOPS through C++ since last few months. That why there is a need of a construct like class?

Comment: There isn't. Look at C, they do fine. Just compare the code you see written using C idioms to code written using C++ or Java idioms.

Comment: Are asking about class in C++ vs struct or about class concept in general? Your question is very broad, it's hard to tell what exactly is your question/problem.

Comment: I can simplify my question with following statement.  "why C++ creators created class to provide abstraction"

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for classes in object-oriented programming. There are lots of languages which do just fine without them: Self, Io, Ioke, Seph, Slate, NewtonScript and ECMAScript have only objects, no classes. Other languages have mixins. Yet other languages have traits. Some languages have classes and mixins, some classes and traits.

The only thing you *really* need for object-orientation is some way to perform procedural abstraction. That's it. Lambda Calculus is a perfectly fine OO language, in fact, since it has *only* procedural (well, actually functional) abstraction and *nothing* else, one might argue that Lambda Calculus is the purest OO language of all.